# Using "if" to describe the past

Tags: tense, past-tense

"This morning, I interviewed my students to see if they like me or not."

Or

"This morning, I interviewed my students to see if they liked me or not."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [He said that his job IS/WAS boring](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/he-said-that-his-job-is-was-boring)

Comment: For your specific example, native speakers would normally "backshift" ***liked*** to match preceding Past Tense ***interviewed***, even if the speaker was actually interested in knowing whether the students liked him *in the general sense* (including present and future, not just at some time in the past). But Present Tense ***like*** would also be perfectly valid for that context; it's just less common.

Comment: Note that ***like*** isn't the best verb for an example here, because usually if you like someone, it's a continuous state that doesn't really make us think in terms of it being an "event" that can be located in time. A better example might be *I asked whether they **watch/watched** the news*, where Present Tense ***watch*** unambiguously conveys that I was asking whether they watch the news on a regular/ongoing basis, but Past Tense ***watched*** could mean the same, OR it could mean I wanted to know if they'd watched the news ***last night in particular*** (and thus knew what had happened).

Comment: @FumbleFingers is surely right about "like"  If they liked him in the morning one hopes that they still do.  But a very slight change of words puts the sentence unambiguously into reported speech, requiring the past tense: "This morning, I asked my students whether they liked me or not". Does the use of "interviewed" change that situation? I don't see why it should.

Comment: Actual "reported speech" is just one common context where this kind of backshifting occurs. But it would be *exactly the same* syntactic issue in, for example, *I wondered if they **liked** me*. Although the "non-backshifted" version *I wondered if they **like** me* is significantly less likely, it doesn't sound completely ridiculous to me, But for reasons I can't easily pin down, *He wondered if they **like** him* doesn't really seem credible to me in *any* context.

Comment: I wanted to see if the students liked me or I wanted to see if the students like me. The meanings are somewhat different. For me, the semantics comes into play not whether one is grammatical or not. They both are grammatical.

Comment: Also, it is generally considered more correct (that is, most style manuals specify it) to use *whether* rather then *if* when referring to possible choices. If you leave out the *or not*, it's better to use *if*.

Comment: @Lambie: By that token, you should also say there's a meaningful *semantic* difference between *I told him my name was FumbleFingers* and *I told him my name **is** FumbleFingers*. But I can't see that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, but there can be a difference. I told him my name was FumbleFingers [which it isn't now.] I told him my name is FumbleFingers [as rightly it is or still is]. This is just an example. Not a semantic difference, a difference in tenses indicating a different state or condition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It just occurred to me that the OP's sentence should read: I interviewed my students to see ***whether*** they like me.

Comment: @Lambie: ***could** read*, sure. But ***should** read?* I never heard of that one as a potential grammatical bone of contention. When I googled for a possible distinction, all I found was [***Whether** and **if** can be used interchangeably in the following circumstances: 1: **When reporting yes/no questions**, 2: **In whether/if...or...constructions**.*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/if_and_whether.htm)